# Can't find how to load the library that contains Get-MsolUser

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I try to use Get-MsolUser; I get the Following message:

> ***Get-MsolUser*** : Le terme «Get-MsolUser» n'est pas reconnu comme nom
>   d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme
>   exécutable.

In english :

> ***Get-MsolUser*** : The term 'Get-MsolUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

How can I get my hands on whatever package contains this cmdlet?

Answer (score 3):

From : [Powershell : The term 'Get-MsolUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://www.morgantechspace.com/2018/06/powershell-get-msoluser-is-not-loaded.html)

The cmdlet Get-MsolUser belongs to Azure AD Powershell (V1) module (MSOnline), so before using this command we need to install and connect MSOnline module.

**Install MSOnline module:**

Earlier you need to download an executable (exe binary) file to install this module, but now Microsoft expired that file and you can install only through powershell. Open Powershell console with Run as administrator privilege and run the following command:

```
Install-Module MSOnline -Force
```

**Connect/Import MSOnline module:**

Once you have installed the MSOnline module, run the following command to connect MSOnline module.

```
Connect-MsolService
# Once you connect MsolService, now run the Get-MsolUser command.
Get-MsolUser
```

**Note:** this is the older MSOnline V1 PowerShell module for Azure Active Directory. Customers are encouraged to use the newer Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module instead of this module. For more information about the V2 module please see [Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).